# Propagating uncertainty in least squares regression

Tags: nonlinear-regression, generalized-least-squares, total-least-squares

I am currently running a nonlinear regression on $y=f(x,\theta)$, the variable $x$ being a known input and $y$ being a measurement result. I would like to estimate the parameters $\theta$ as well as their covariance, $V_\theta$. I already have a reasonable estimate of $\theta$.

My current issue is the real eq is $y+\eta=f(x+\epsilon,\theta)$, and both $\eta$ and $\epsilon$ have a known covariance (but are independent of each other). I am well aware of generalised least squares (GLS), and I know total least squares (TLS) exist. Before I dive into TLS, I was thinking: since I already have a reasonable estimate of $\theta$, could I update my known $V_\eta$ by propagating $V_\epsilon$, since I already have a reasonable estimate of $\theta$, creating $y+\nu=f(x+\epsilon,\theta)$, with $V_\nu = V_y + JV_xJ^T$.

The approach is very similar to the [wiki page on TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares), under the header "Allowing observation errors in all variables".

I have been struggling to find any additional information that expands on this approach, every TLS approach seems to be using SVD. I'd like to explore this first since this would only modify GLS, which I am very familiar with and am knowledgeable on the set of rules needed to have confidence the GLS is working correctly.

I'd be grateful to know if anyone has working knowledge on this approach, or can confirm it gives unbiased results.

Comment: Have you looked at the Scaled Total Least Squares?